# What the ... are all of you studying/working for asking such questions?

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, quants

Sry, I'm new here. But I am just astonished by all those sick questions and answers you ask/provide... Are most of you studying mathematics or are your finance programs that good, that you can ask/answer such mathematical questions?
Or did you learn those things after many years at work?
I'm about to finish my master's program and I'm really afraid not to find a job because of people like you...

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to downvote this question for not being relevant in particular to quantitative finance nor programming but I will give you the benefit of the doubt. I too am new to this community yet I can tell you that we are all deeply interested and passionate about the topic. Some of us are undergrad, some postgrads, some make their career out of this and others just do this for leisure. It's all about your attitude to your work and consulting help where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think most of us, at some point of time, studied a lot of math. Quant finance is pretty much very mathematical. Even the physicists or computer scientists I met at work are all pretty good with math. So yes if you are still in a master's program and if you find these quant finance questions intimidating then maybe it's helpful to do a couple more courses in Mathematics, at least Stochastic calculus. Just my 2 cents. More math will definitely help you down the pipe.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I expected. I would say 70% of our master's program was maths as well. But definitely not on the level of those questions here. That's why I was wondering if all of you did so much more maths during your finance master or if you still learned a that much afterwards at work.

Comment: It might be difficult to just join some math courses of another program. Would a certificate, like CFA or FRM, help to improve those kind of maths skills?

Comment: Unfortunately CFA and FRM doesn't help much. Most of CFA's curriculum is non-mathematical (a lot of accounting actually because CFA chart holders needs to be good at reading accounting statements to do financial analysis work to pick companies and stocks). FRM has some math but won't provide the hardcore ones you need for quant finance. I personally don't know many quants that actually had CFAs or FRMs.

Comment: Thanks, nice to get to see the perspective of a practitioner. So a mathematics program is inevitable? I really regret not starting mathematics earlier. But now it feels like it's too late for me. I wouldn't want to attach 5 more years of Uni. Feels like I need to do 3 years of very theoretical stuff and the applied part comes at the master's level. Learning those maths things at work is unrealistic, right?

Comment: You are welcome. Leaning math at work is difficult. Finance is broad field however. Quant finance is only a small subset of it so spending many years to just do quant finance may not be ideal. If you come from a good finance program then there are jobs available that outside of quant finance that pays equally well.